# Arrays and Datatypes in Z3py

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm actually using Z3py for scheduling solving problems and I'm trying to represent a 2 processors system where 4 process of different execution time must be done.

My actual data are :
Process 1 : Arrival at 0 and execution time of 4
Process 2 : Arrival at 1 and execution time of 3
Process 3 : Arrival at 3 and execution time of 5
Process 4 : Arrival at 1 and execution time of 2

I'm actually trying to represent each process while decomposing each in subprocess of equal time so my datatypes are like this :

```
Pn = Datatype('Pn')
Pn.declare('1')
Pn.declare('2')
Pn.declare('3')
Pn.declare('4')
Pt = Datatype('Pt')
Pt.declare('1')
Pt.declare('2')
Pt.declare('3')
Pt.declare('4')
Pt.declare('5')
Process = Datatype('Process')
Process.declare('cons' , ('name',Pn) , ('time', Pt))
Process.declare('idle')
```

where pn and pt are the process name and the part of the process (process 1 is in 4 parts, ...)

But now I don't know how I can represent my processors to add 3 rules I need : unicity (each sub process must be done 1 and only 1 time by only 1 processor) check arrival (the first part of a process can't be processed before it arrived) and order (each part of a process must be processed after the precedent)
So I was thinking of using arrays to represent my 2 processors with this kind of declaration :

```
P = Array('P', IntSort() , Process)
```

But when I tried to execute it I got an error message saying :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alexis\Desktop\test.py", line 16, in <module>
    P = Array('P', IntSort() , Process)
  File "src/api/python\z3.py", line 3887, in Array
  File "src/api/python\z3.py", line 3873, in ArraySort
  File "src/api/python\z3.py", line 56, in _z3_assert
Z3Exception: 'Z3 sort expected'
```

And know I don't know how handle it... must I create a new datatype and figure a way to add my rules ? or Is there a way to add datatypes to array which would let me create rules like this :

```
unicity = ForAll([x,y] , (Implies(x!=y,P[x]!=P[y])))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tutorial on using Datatypes from the Python API. A link to the tutorial is:
     http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorialcontent/advanced#h22
It shows how to create a list data-type and use the "create()" method to instantiate a Sort object from the object used when declaring the data-type. For your example, it suffices to add calls to "create()" in the places where you want to use the declared type as a sort.
See: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/rQ7t

Regarding the rest of the case study you are looking at: it is certainly possible to express the constrsaints you describe using quantifiers and arrays. You could also consider somewhat more efficient encodings:

- Instead of using an array, use a function declaration. So P would be declared as a unary function:
  P = Function('P', IntSort(), Process.create()).
- Using quantifiers for small finite domain problems may be more of an overhead than a benefit. Writing down the constraints directly as a finite conjunction saves the overhead of instantiating quantifiers possibly repeatedly. That said, some quantified axioms can also be optimized. Z3 automatically compiles axioms of the form: ForAll([x,y], Implies(x != y, P(x) != P(y))) into 
  an axioms of the form Forall([x], Pinv(P(x)) == x), where "Pinv" is a fresh function. The new axiom still enforces that P is injective but requires only a linear number of instantiations, linear in the number of occurrences of P(t) for some term 't'.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, It helped me to continue (I didn't see the create() method in the tutorial...) But now I'm stuck because when I try to get a model with unicity (I adapted it to 2 arrays) I only obtain arrays that for all indexes we get idle... (0->idle ,else->idle) and I don't know how to change that... So I still have a long way to go ^^